# Insert a value in one table if it is not present in another

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, hiveql

I have two tables, `Table1` and `Table2`. Table1 has only one column, let's say `Id`. `Table2` has multiple other columns besides `Id` I need to write a hive query to first check if a given `Id` is present in the Id column of `Table1` or not. If the Id is not present I need to insert it into `Table2` otherwise insert `null`.

Eg:

Table1

```
----Id1------
"abcde"
"ghdis"
----------
```

Now I suppose I am given a value "sjsnx". The query should run through `Table1` and insert `"sjsnx"` in `Table2`.
If I am given `"abcde"` as value, the query should insert null in `Table2`.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use `not exists` to get the ids that are in `table1` but not `table2`:

```
insert into table2 (id, . . . )
    select t1.id, . . . 
    from table1 t1
    where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.id = t1.id);
```

The `. . .`  is for the other columns and their values.

Comment: What will be inserted in id column of Table2 if value is not present in Table1?

Comment: @AkshatChoudhary . . . I interpret "not present" as "not present in table2".  Otherwise, the question doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a code in some programming language *(maybe SHELL, Python, etc)*. This cannot be done in one shot using hive since your requirement needs to do two database INSERTS. Also for your input requirement, you can leverage Hive config parameter using SET values to search for IDs.

Your code will look something as below in SHELL:

Checking the first table:

```
 search_id='<your search id>'

 table1search_var=`hive -S -e "select id from table1 where id=${hiveconfig:db_search_id}" --hiveconfig:db_search_id=$search_id`;
 
 if [ -z "$table1search_var" ];
 then
   echo "Found Null row. Hence inserting search id into table2"
   hive -S -e "insert into table2(id) values('$search_id')"
 
 else
   echo "Found Not Null rows. Hence inserting NULL into table2"
   hive -S -e "insert into table2(id) values(null)"
 
 fi
```

Hope this helps :)